# Howto use std::thread in this scenerio?

Tags: c++, qt, stdthread

I've wrote an `HTTP` upload/download class using [QNetworkAccessManager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details) and I use it like below:-

```
    int main(..){
    
        QCoreApplication app(...);
        HTTP http(&app);
    
        QNetworkRequest DownloadRequest;
        QNetworkRequest UploadRequest;
    
        UploadRequest.setUrl(QUrl("path/to/server"));
    
        http.UploadFile(UploadRequest, (QFileInfo)"path/to/file1");
        http.UploadFile(UploadRequest, (QFileInfo)"path/to/file2");
        http.UploadFile(UploadRequest, (QFileInfo)"path/to/file3");
    
        DownloadRequest.setUrl(QUrl("link/to/fileX"));
        http.DownloadFile(DownloadRequest);
        
        app.exec();
}
```

Now I want to embed this module in another C++ project. So I created a `std::thread` (not a `Qthread`) and moved `QCoreApplication` & `app.exec()` to avoid being pause in the event loop like below

```
int main(..){

 std::thread UploadDownloadModule(..);   // This thread upload/download stuff but get stuck in app.exec() (howto quit this thread once it get finished ?, should i use QCoreApplication::quit() here ?

// do some stuff here

}
```

I want UploadDownloadModule(..) to get finished (`exit` the thread, not stuck in app.exec() loop) once the download/upload process completes. I would also like to invoke UploadDownloadModule(..) on request.

How should I design my app to meet the above criteria?

Comment: `(QFileInfo)"path/to/file1"` it hurts my eyes. Just do `QFileInfo{"path/to/file1"}`.

Comment: Why do you think you need threads? You are using asynchronous API, so nothing blocks. In fact introducing threads creates problems and doesn't solving any in this case.

Comment: Looks an xy-problem.  Can you explain why you need to create the `QCoreApplication` instance on a thread *other* than that on which `main` is running?  As far as I'm aware that's unsupported.

Comment: `app.exec()` do not "stuck your app" it just runs event loop. Every Qt application have to have it. So when something is happen this runs respective event handler/slot. It does nothing only when there nothing to do. Please read more carefully something about `QApplication` and how asynchronous API works in Qt.

Comment: @noob_user Just to clarify, apparently your main problem is understanding how Qt was designed. It would be best if you provide more details: 1. What exactly your application suppose to do (from end user point of view). 2. Show us you magical code behind `HTTP`. 3. Describe exactly on what yoo have stack on. Avoid describing how you try to fix it. Your question clearly suffers form [XY-problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) (please read link), so we have no idea what your actual problem is.

Comment: @MarekR I think I understand the user's problem. They might be asking how to perform their own function calls within QT's main thread.

Comment: Why not use QThread if you are using QT already?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mislead on when to use threads and how to use them. `app.exec()` isn't halting executing of your main thread, rather and I don't use Qt so it's an assumption but it's a loop which checks for user input and sends them to appropriate callbacks, similar to the Windows message loop which you might be familiar with..

```
while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 )) != 0)
    { 
        if (bRet == -1)
        {
            // handle the error and possibly exit
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg); 
            DispatchMessage(&msg); 
        }
    }
```

But you'd like to execute UploadDownloadModules in a separate thread; however if you're waiting for them to complete before calling app.exec(), then it seems making a thread here is redundant. What difference would it make if you were to call the code in your main function and wait for it to complete?
The ideal scenario here would be to use app's thread loop to execute your upload/download callbacks. Now I don't know how QT works because I've never used it so I'll give a basic example of how it could be done and I would assume considering how massive QT is that they have an implementation for it already.

Let's assume I have a thread which checks for input, and executes a callback.

```
void UIApplication::run(){
  int input = 0;
  do{
    input = CheckForInput(..);
    SomeCallback(input);
  }while( input );
}
```

Now if I was the one designing UIApplication I would let the users/developers add their own callbacks in the loop to be performed along with my thread loop. So long as it doesn't halt the execution of the application.

```
class UIApplication{
public:
    void Run(){
        for(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<struct TStruct> >::iterator it = tvec.begin();it!=tvec.end();++it){
            std::shared_ptr<struct TStruct> s = *it;
            s->fu = std::async(std::launch::async, [s] {
                s->f(s->ctx);
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(s->ms);
                return true;
            });
            
        }
        do{
            
            for(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<struct TStruct> >::iterator it = tvec.begin();it!=tvec.end();++it){
                std::shared_ptr<struct TStruct> s = *it;
                auto status = s->fu.wait_for(0ms);
                if (status == std::future_status::ready) {
                    std::cout << "Thread finished" << std::endl;
                    s->fu = std::async(std::launch::async, [s] {
                        s->f(s->ctx);
                        std::this_thread::sleep_for(s->ms);
                        return true;
                    });
                } else {
                    //running
                }
            }
            //DO MAIN UI STUFF HERE
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
            
        }while(1);
    }
    void PerformAlongSideThread(std::function<void(uint64_t)> f,uint64_t ctx,uint64_t ms){
        std::shared_ptr<TStruct> t = std::make_shared<TStruct>();
        t->f = f;
        t->ctx = ctx;
        t->ms = std::chrono::milliseconds(ms);
        tvec.push_back(t);
        
    }
private:
    struct TStruct{
        std::function<void(uint64_t)> f;
        uint64_t ctx;
        std::chrono::milliseconds ms;
        std::future<bool> fu;
    };
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<struct TStruct> >  tvec;
    
};
```

Then the developers could create an instance of UIApplication and perform my tasks along with its own tasks

```
int main(){
    UIApplication app;
    
    app.PerformAlongSideThread(customthread1, 10,1000);
    app.PerformAlongSideThread(customthread2, 20,2000);
    app.Run();
    return 0;
}
```

This will tell UIApplication main thread to execute customthread1 with context 10 every 1000 miliseconds and customthread2, with context 20 every 2000 miliseconds. The context here is arbitrary and could be anything.
This is just a demonstration and it might not be how QT does it but I hope it clears some things up about your question.